# jquery select by two condition

Tags: jquery

I like to select an element by more than two condition.

for example

name is some name and  checked

how can I do this?

Comment: 7 view and 3answer.  thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append the [attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selectors, like this:

```
$("[name=myName]:checked")
```

Th key here, **don't** leave a space and you're telling Sizzle (jQuery's selector engine) to filter on the *same* element.  If you put a space between, it's would be: "find checked *children* of elements with this name."

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
if ($('input[name="some_name"]').is(':checked'))
{
  // your code here...........
}
```

This makes sure that it checks only for form `input` which is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses CSS Selector rules for document matchings.
if you know how to use CSS Selectors you will know how to do this
use this as reference
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

and read more about CSS Selectors

Comment: While this is partially true, jQuery implements CSS selectors *and* some others, for example `:animated` isn't in CSS :)

Comment: I didn't mention it in the post because it was already written in the link that I provided. any how thanks for your notice I will include more accurate information in my next posts